# Is it possible to make views in the header of a RecyclerView navigation drawer clickable?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, onclicklistener

I am creating an android app which has a navigation drawer. The header of the drawer has a circular ImageView and some TextViews. I want to make them clickable. I have been trying to fix this for hours but in vain. After searching the web for a while I got hints (though I am not sure) that the header is not clickable at least by default. Is it true? Is it possible to make the views in the header of my drawer clickable? I have tried setting setClickable() to true etc but nothing works. Please help. Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: They will be clickable if you add the click listener on individual component of header. How you are adding header in navigation drawer?

Comment: @EEJ Please see the edit. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You can get Individual component event by getting header view like this.
addHeaderView(header, null, false) disable click event of entire header but you can get component event using View.

```
View header = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.header, null);
mDrawerList.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
ImageView image = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.image_id);
image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                   Log.e("","Click event")
            }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But unfortunately I have used RecyclerView for my drawer and this won't work in that case. Thanks for the response anyways !!